# Saving related models in Phalcon on a manyToMany (N-N) relationship

Tags: model, phalcon

I have three database tables; `contents`, `contents_tags`, and `tags`. I want to add a new entry to `contents`, but I keep getting the error `Cursor is an immutable ArrayAccess object`.

I have been following [this section of the manual regarding saving related records](http://docs.phalconphp.com/pt/latest/reference/models.html#storing-related-records). And this [forum post concerning setting up the relationships](http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/545/many-to-many-relation). All to no avail. I think it's something idiotically simple like plurals on the class names, but I can't see it.

**This is my test code:**

```
$content                = new Content();
$content->title         = 'xkcd';
$content->description   = 'description goes here';
$content->url           = 'http://xkcd.com/';
$content->created_on    = new Phalcon\Db\RawValue('NOW()');
$content->tags          = array();

$tagsText = 'xkcd,comics,testing';

foreach(explode(',', $tagsText) as $tagText) {
    $tag = new Tag();
    $tag->tag = trim($tagText);
    $content->tags[] = $tag;
}

if($content->save()) {
    $app->response->setStatusCode(201, "Created");
    $app->response->setJsonContent($content->overview());
} else {
    $app->response->setStatusCode(400, "Bad Request");
    $app->response->setJsonContent(array('errors'=>$content->getMessagesAsArray()));
}
```

**Contents model:**

```
class Content {
    public function initialize() {
        $this->hasManyToMany(
            'id',
            'ContentsTags',
            'content_id',
            'tag_id',
            'Tag',
            'id',
            array('alias' => 'tags')
        );
    }

    public function getSource() {
        return 'contents';
    }
}
```

**ContentsTag model:**

```
class ContentsTags {

    public function initialize() {
        $this->belongsTo('content_id', 'Content', 'id', array('alias' => 'content'));
        $this->belongsTo('tag_id', 'Tag', 'id', array('alias' => 'tag'));
    }

    public function getSource() {
        return 'contents_tags';
    }
}
```

**Tag model:**

```
class Tag {

    public function getSource() {
        return 'tags';
    }

    public function initialize() {
        $this->hasManyToMany(
            'id',
            'ContentsTags',
            'tag_id',
            'content_id',
            'Content',
            'id',
            array('alias' => 'contents')
        );
    }
}
```

**Final Output:**

```
{"error":"Cursor is an immutable ArrayAccess object"}
```

Can anyone see where I am messing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was looking in the wrong place. You can't address related items as an array in that manner, you have to do this:

```
$tags = array();
foreach(explode(',', $tagsText) as $tagText) {
    $tag = new Tag();
    $tag->tag = trim($tagText);
    $tags[] = $tag;
}
$content->tags = $tags;
```